# Residual spectrum is empty

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm following Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" and am trying to follow the proof of the following Theorem (9.2-4 on p. 468)

*For a bounded self-adjoint linear operator $T:H\to H$  on a complex Hilbert space $H$, $$\sigma_{r}\left(T\right)=\emptyset,$$
i.e. its residual spectrum is empty.*

The proof refers to the following Lemma:

**Lemma** (projection theorem) Suppose that $Y$
is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Then 
$$
H=Y\oplus Y^{\perp}.
$$

Kreysig's begins his argument as follows.

"*Suppose, for contradiction, that $\sigma_{r}\left(T\right)$ is non-empty;
indeed, pick $\lambda\in\sigma_{r}\left(T\right)$. Then by definition of the residual spectrum, $R_{\lambda}:=T_{\lambda}^{-1}=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$
exists but its domain is not dense in $H$.*"

I understand everything so far. He then goes to argue:

*"Hence by the Projection Theorem, there is a $y \neq 0$ in $H$ which is orthogonal to the domain of $R_{\lambda}$."*

I don't see why this is. I wonder if someone could very kindly explain?

Comment: Denote $Y=\operatorname{Im}(R_\lambda)$, then $Y$ is a proper subspace of $H$. By projection theorem $Y^\perp\neq\{0\}$, so you can choose $y\in Y^\perp\setminus\{0\}$ which is by definition of $Y^\perp$ orthogonal to $Y$, i.e. to $\operatorname{Im}(R_\lambda)$.

Comment: But aren't we looking for $y \neq 0$ in $H$ which is orthogonal to the *domain* of $R_{\lambda}$, not its image?

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment you should substitute $R_\lambda$ with $T_\lambda$ then $Y$ will be the domain of $R_\lambda$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $Y=\operatorname{Im}(T_\lambda)$, then $Y$ is a proper subspace of $H$. By projection theorem $Y^\perp\neq \{0\}$, so you can choose $y\in Y^\perp\setminus\{0\}$ which is by definition of $Y$ is orthogonal to $Y$, i.e. to $\operatorname{Im}(T_\lambda)$